# Error importing a static class from default package in java

Tags: java, import, static

I am trying to cut short the `System.out.println()` by defining a static method inside `Util.java`. I would like to make use of Util.print() further shortened into `print()`. So I have did a static import.

Util.java is present under the same directory as ListOfNumbers.java. When I try to access writeList() from a tester class I get the below error:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static Util;

public class ListOfNumbers {
    ...
    ...
    public void writeList() {
    // The FileWriter constructor throws IOException, which must be caught.
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            print("Entered try statement...");
            ...
        } catch (IOException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e){            
            print("Exception thrown: \n" + e.getMessage());
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
>> javac Tester.java && java Tester
.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: '.' expected
import static Util;
                  ^
.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: ';' expected
import static Util;
                   ^
.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import static Util;
              ^
  symbol: class Util
.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static Util;
^
.\ListOfNumbers.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        print("Entered try statement...");
                        ^
  symbol:   method print(String)
  location: class ListOfNumbers
.\ListOfNumbers.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                        print("Exception thrown: \n" + e.getMessage());
                        ^
  symbol:   method print(String)
  location: class ListOfNumbers
6 errors
```

Comment: Doesn't look like that answered my question. Can you have a closer look at the current context and the question you "possibly" marked as duplicate?

Comment: Well if you read the answer and subsequent question tagged in the answer that should clear your doubt.

Comment: And just for the record: using the default package is bad practice and really really not something you should do. And the names of classes should say what they "are"; and in that sense "Util" isn't exactly an example of great naming either.

Comment: @Jägermeister: Valid points and agreed! I am trying to implement and learn some of the basics and practice. However I would keep it in mind while working with default package names. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782076/static-import-only-from-classes-and-interfaces

Answer (score 4):

You should import the method name

```
import static Util.print;
```

If you want to import all static methods from Util:

```
import static Util.*;
```

Comment: hi Rajesh, thanks for sharing.. I have done as you suggested. Now getting the below error..

.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import static Util.print;
              ^
  symbol: class Util
.\ListOfNumbers.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces

Comment: Have a package definition for your classes. static import from default package is not possible http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4989710

Answer (score 1):

The below answer helped me to overcome the problem! Guess this must be a bug.

[Java static member from default package cannot be imported!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963983/in-java-static-members-of-the-default-package-cannot-be-imported-can-some-on)